# Modelling Entity Relationship in SQLite Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have been learning to use SQLite ROOM persistance library for a while.
To implement it in my existing project using Graph Algorithm I need to model following scenario.

```
Class  Vertex{
int id,
double lat,longi;
}

Class Edge{
int id;
Vertex source;
Vertex Destination;
}

Class Route{
List<Vertex> vertex_list;


}
```

Now I want to create three different tables for three entities.
My table is like this

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_VERTEX + "("
                + VERTEX_ROWID + "  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + VERTEX_NAME
                + " VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, " + VERTEX_REF_STOP
                + " VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL, " + VERTEX_LAT
                + " DOUBLE NOT NULL, "
                + VERTEX_LONG + " DOUBLE NOT NULL, " + VERTEX_ISTRANSIT
                + " TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', " + VERTEX_NAME_NEPALI
                + " VARCHAR(255) ); ");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_EDGE + "(" + EDGE_ID
                + "  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + EDGE_REF_STOP
                + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + EDGE_SOURCE_STOP
                + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + EDGE_DEST_STOP
                + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + EDGE_DISTANCE
                + " DOUBLE NOT NULL, "
                + EDGE_ONEWAY + " TINYINT NOT NULL); ");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_ROUTE + "(" + ROUTE_ID
                + "  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + ROUTE_NAME
                + " VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "  + ROUTE_STOPS
                + " VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, " + ROUTE_VEHICLETYPE
                ");
```

My problem is I want to directly retrieve the record of source and destination while i get the records of edge.
And Also I want to retrieve all the edge list while retrieving route record.
Can somebody please explain how can I achieve this?

(Updated:) My problem is not with inserting data. I am importing the data from server. I want to retrieve the record saved in database as per my model class using Room Persistence Library.

Comment: do you know sql? if you do, edit your question and  add what you want in sql statements.

Comment: Could you give sample db-content (e.g. as a set of lines "create table ..." and "insert into ..." and desired result?